# Updated my Github password and now I can not push to Github

Tags: python, macos, github, terminal, passwords

I get an image of a key in terminal when I am prompted to add my password and it will not let me manually type a password. When I press enter it gives me an error that the password is incorrect.

I tried the following code with no success (I still get the key image):

git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https

I also tried updating my password in the KeyChain Access app but I can not find anything for Github there.

Answer (score 1):

[Git cache](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache) your credentials in memory. The default timeout is 900s i.e. 15 min.

You can invalidate git cache by this `git credential-cache exit` command.

The best practice would be configuring the [ssh keys in github](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
git remote show origin
```

And see if you can update your password